# SSIS variable syntax for ForEach Loop Container

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis, etl

I am still learning SSIS and variables, and have a question regarding syntax.

For the first time I am using a ForEach Loop Container in a package. The ForEach will scan a server folder, a variable will create a new subfolder titled with the customer order number, and finally create 6 new subfolders in the customer order number folder.

My question is, instead of creating variables for each of the 6 subfolders created in the customer order number folder, can they be combined into one variable. Below is the expression that I came up with, but it just doesn’t look right.

```
"[1. Estimates"+"[2. Contract]"+"[3. Purchase Order]"+"[4. Sales Order]"+"[5. Processing]"+"[6. Shipping]"
```

Any assistance on the syntax is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a loop for these inside of your other loop.

You could use an Execute SQL Task to select these into an object variable, and then iterate over that variable using For Each ADO Enumerator, assigning the selected value (of those six) to a variable which will append to another variable containing your full path.

You can then execute a File System Task to create your directory within that inner loop.